# IOS: Stay on the first view controller before complete all controls (StoryBoard)

Tags: ios, storyboard, push, segue

[image]

I connected first view controller with the second one using StoryBoard Push Segue and Interface Builder.

The button is named GO on top/right.

I have three textfield that must be filled before going to second controller.

I display an alert when one of them is empty.

The problem is that my code after displaying correct alertView goes to SecondController instead of remaining on mainController.

```
 if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DataDisplay"])
{
    if (![self verifySelection]) {
        return;
    } else {
        RowViewController *rowViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
//        rowViewController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You have a segue wired directly from your `Go` button to your `Sensor Data` view controller.  You don't want this, because anytime someone touches `Go`, the segue is going to happen ... no stopping it.  So, first step is to remove the `segue` you have going from `Go` to your second view controller.

2) Instead, wire the segue from the `File's Owner` icon below the view controller to the second view controller.  Give it a name like `DataDisplay`.

3) In the `IBAction` for your `Go button`

```
if ([self verifySelection) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DataDisplay" sender:self]
}
```

Comment: Yes. IT WORKS. I would like to see the arrow in the StoryBoard for logical purpose but it doesn't matter. Thank you.

Comment: ops sorry I have this error: Receiver (<TableViewController: 0x756f7c0>) has no segue with identifier 'DataDisplay''

Comment: Did you do step 2 above?  You still need to set up a segue, but it should be from the view controller, not from the `Go` button.  Be sure to set its identifier to `DataDisplay`.  You should see an arrow with a segue icon from your first view controller to the second.

Answer (score 1):

An easy fix would be to create the segue manually, rather than letting the interface builder manage it. So you would ctrl-drag from your main view controller to your second one, selecting push as the type of segue and assigning it an identifier through the identifier inspector, then you connect an IBAction to your Go button and in the method you perform the checks on the text fields before programmatically firing the segue with:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"whateverIdentifierYouGaveYourSegue" sender:self];
```

Heads up: to create a manual segue from a viewcontroller to another one, you need to either zoom out in your storyboard or ctrl-drag from the yellow circle underneath the view!

Edit: Your IBAction connected to the button method should be something like the following:

```
- (IBAction)download:(id)sender {
    if(text boxes are ok)
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:self];
    else
        [self showWarning];
}
```

Make sure that you assigned the ID segueIdentifier to the segue you created in your storyboard.

Comment: If it worked for you, can you select my answer as correct? (Green tick under the up/down votes) Thanks!

Comment: The above answer should work.  If you are transitioning to the second view controller without calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` then you must have one wired directly to your go button.  You don't want that.

Comment: Do you mean that it doesn't transition to your second view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are defining the "performSegueWithIdentifier" after displaying the alert.

I think the code you are doing is like this :

//AlertView Allocation
[alert show];
Perform Segue

If this is how you are doing, then you are doing it wrong.

You have to use the structure of If-Else Statements and put up the Perform Segue in the condition where all the textfields are filled.

Comment: I put my code and it's the same as you mention...but don't work...go to second controller directly